# using xqsuite for library modules in exist-db

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I like to write library modules that can be executed simply by calling the xq file. However, these also contain functions that I would like to test. Something like this `some.xql`:

```
xquery version "3.0";
 import module namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
 declare namespace no="http://none";
 declare namespace test="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite";

 declare 
    %test:arg('1')
    %test:assertEquals('2')
    function no:something ($num as xs:string?) as xs:string {
     return 
          $num + 1
};

 xmldb:store('/db/data/', 'two.xml',<root>{no:something(1)}</root>)
```

However I cannot test the whole module or the no:something function from within it. I have no problem accessing the function in other context using:

`import module namespace no="http://none" at "some.xql";`

Yet, when trying to run test suite from a wrapper function I keep getting xpty00004 errors:

```
xquery version "3.0";
 import module namespace test="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite" at "resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/xqsuite/xqsuite.xql";
 test:suite(
     inspect:module-functions(xs:anyURI("some.xql"))
)
```

I have tried different variation of getting to the `no:some` function, but no lock. Am I just writing really bad queries, using the xqsuite wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `some.xql` is a *main module*, you can only import and test functions in *library modules*.

Consider instead refactoring to a library module like `no.xqm`:

```
xquery version "3.0";

module namespace no="http://none";

declare namespace test="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite";

declare 
  %test:arg('1')
  %test:assertEquals('2')
function no:something ($num as xs:string?) as xs:string {
  $num + 1
};
```

Your app main module `some.xq`:

```
xquery version "3.0";

import module namespace no="http://none" at "no.xqm";

xmldb:store('/db/data/', 'two.xml',<root>{no:something(1)}</root>
```

Your test runner main module `tests.xq`:

```
xquery version "3.0";
import module namespace test="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite" 
at "resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/xqsuite/xqsuite.xql";

test:suite(
    inspect:module-functions(xs:anyURI("no.xqm"))
)
```

Comment: I was afraid that this is the case. But now I know. Thanks for the detailed answer.